# Summarising data in a list in R

Tags: r, sapply, tapply

I have numerous dataframes all contained in a list called `1a1` the names in the list are dates when data were collected e.g.

```
 names(1a1)
[1] "Jan4" "Jan5" "Jan6" "Jan7" "Jan8" "Jan9" "Jan10"
```

all the dataframes in the list are in the same format

e.g.

```
 dput(Jan4)
structure(list(Species = c("bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", 
"bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", 
"bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", 
"bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", 
"bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", 
"bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", 
"bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", 
"bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "bluti", "greti", "greti", "greti", 
"greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", 
"greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", 
"greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", 
"greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", 
"greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", "greti", 
"greti", "greti", "greti", "greti"), Pit.tag = c("01103FD6EF", 
"01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", 
"01103FD77C", "01103FD77C", "01103FD77C", "01103FD77C", "01103FD6EF", 
"01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", 
"01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", 
"01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", 
"01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD77C", "01103FD77C", "01103FD77C", 
"01103FD77C", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", 
"01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", 
"01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", 
"01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103FD6EF", "01103F9F29", 
"01103F9F29", "01103F9F29", "01103F9F29", "0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", 
"0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", 
"0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", 
"0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", 
"0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", "01103F9F29", "01103F9F29", 
"01103F9F29", "01103F9F29", "0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", 
"0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", 
"0700EDADB8", "0700EDADB8", "01103F9F29", "01103F9F29", "01103F9F29", 
"01103F9F29"), Date = c("04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", 
"04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", 
"04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", 
"04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", 
"04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", 
"04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", 
"04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", 
"04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", 
"04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", 
"04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", 
"04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", 
"04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", 
"04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", 
"04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", 
"04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", 
"04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", 
"04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", 
"04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", 
"04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021", "04-01-2021"), Time = c("08:01:41", 
"08:01:42", "08:01:42", "08:03:09", "08:03:09", "08:03:10", "08:02:57", 
"08:02:57", "08:02:58", "08:03:36", "08:01:41", "08:01:42", "08:01:42", 
"08:03:09", "08:03:09", "08:03:10", "08:01:41", "08:01:42", "08:01:42", 
"08:03:09", "08:03:09", "08:03:10", "08:01:41", "08:01:42", "08:01:42", 
"08:03:09", "08:03:09", "08:03:10", "08:02:57", "08:02:57", "08:02:58", 
"08:03:36", "08:01:41", "08:01:42", "08:01:42", "08:03:09", "08:03:09", 
"08:03:10", "08:01:41", "08:01:42", "08:01:42", "08:03:09", "08:03:09", 
"08:03:10", "08:01:41", "08:01:42", "08:01:42", "08:03:09", "08:03:09", 
"08:03:10", "08:02:26", "08:02:26", "08:03:37", "08:03:38", "08:00:43", 
"08:00:44", "08:00:44", "08:01:39", "08:01:39", "08:01:40", "08:01:40", 
"08:02:54", "08:02:54", "08:02:55", "08:00:43", "08:00:44", "08:00:44", 
"08:01:39", "08:01:39", "08:01:40", "08:01:40", "08:02:54", "08:02:54", 
"08:02:55", "08:02:26", "08:02:26", "08:03:37", "08:03:38", "08:00:43", 
"08:00:44", "08:00:44", "08:01:39", "08:01:39", "08:01:40", "08:01:40", 
"08:02:54", "08:02:54", "08:02:55", "08:02:26", "08:02:26", "08:03:37", 
"08:03:38")), row.names = c(NA, -92L), class = "data.frame")
```

What I would like to do is create a new dataframe which summarises these data where I can see how many times an idividual `Pit.tag` was seen (create a new variable called `No_of_visits`) and which `Species` it belonged to

e.g.

```
Pit.tag     Species   No_of_visits
01103FD6EF   bluti    47
```

I can get most of the info I need by using variations of

```
Visitsbypit<-sapply(tapply(1a1$`Jan4`$Species, 1a1$`Jan4`$Pit.tag, length), unique)
Vistsbyspecies<-sapply(tapply(1a1$`Jan4`$Pit.tag, 1a1$`Jan4`$Species, length), unique)


Visitsbypit
01103F9776 01103FA8DD 01103FC9DE 
        10        133        255

Vistsbyspecies
greti bluti 
   10   388
```

Note: These data above will not match the data I've provided here they are from another dataframe

This also doesn't really get me what I'm after, so `Visitsbyspecies` is just the total visits by each species and not linked to the `Pit.tag` record. I would like to link the `Pit.tag` records in `Visitsbypit` to their corresponding species

But I can't make the next leap and put this info together.
I'm also thinking that there must be a better way for this to be done across the list rather than having to specify for e.g. `` 1a1$`Jan4`$Species `` that seems to me to defeat the purpose of having the dataframes in a list and using `sapply` and `tapply`

Comment: This is a wild guess because I'm not sure I fully understand the question: are you looking for the `table` function? That you could use like this: `table(Jan4$Species, Jan4$Pit.tag)`?

Comment: Hmm not quite what I was after but it is useful to know this nonetheless. Is my question not clear enough? I did think I'd explained it properly. Apologies if not, I'll look through it again and see if I can clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want this?

```
library(dplyr)

Jan4 %>% count(Species, Pit.tag)

#  Species    Pit.tag  n
#1   bluti 01103FD6EF 42
#2   bluti 01103FD77C  8
#3   greti 01103F9F29 12
#4   greti 0700EDADB8 30
```

To apply to list of dataframes use `lapply`/`purrr::map` -

```
lapply(`1a1`, function(x) x %>% count(Species, Pit.tag))
```